# Copying a list of Model Fields instances in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I find myself stuck with this problem and I might have phrased the title wrong but will explain what I want to do and what I am willing to accomplish. I have a model for attedance and on a daily basis a teacher has to mark an attendance Register. I wouldnt want a situation where when generating a register data has to be captured on a daily basis but I would like were a table like form with a copy of all students in a class created with only status being the fields to be edited and saved, thus on save of each student their day attendance record is created. My model is like as follows:

```
class StudentAttendanceTimeSheet(models.Model):
    DAILY_ATTENDANCE_STATUS_CHOICES = [(1, 'Present'), (2, 'absent'), (3, 'sick')]
   
   student = models.Foreignkey('Student', related_name='attendances', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   attendance_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DAILY_ATTENDANCE_STATUS_CHOICES, default='1')
   date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today())
   class = models.ForeignKey('Class', related_name='class_timesheets, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to make a step form where by when I hit the select button a copy would be made with those fields prepopulated with database data for a specific class. Thus a list of all students enrolled in that class.

May someone help me with how they would create a Django Rest Create View for such a problem. Thanks in advance. Ngiyabonga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I handled this problem

```
from django.db import models
from basedata.models import SoftDeletionModel
from basedata.constants import ATTENDANCE_STATUS_CHOICES
from django.conf import settings


    

class Attendance(SoftDeletionModel):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    klass = models.ForeignKey(
                        'klasses.StudentClass', 
                        models.SET_NULL, 
                        null=True,
                        blank=True,
                        related_name='attendances'
                    )
    recorded_by = models.ForeignKey(
                            "people.StaffUser", 
                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                            related_name='recorder', 
                            null=True
                        )
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Attendance, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.records.count() <= 0:
            for student in self.klass.students.all():
                self.records.create(student=student, status='present') 
        # separate sql query i guess for each entry created.

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}, {self.date}"




class AttendanceRecord(SoftDeletionModel):
    attendance = models.ForeignKey(
                'Attendance', 
                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                null=True, 
                blank=True,
                related_name='records'
            )
    student = models.ForeignKey(
                        'people.Student', 
                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                        blank=True,
                        null=True,
                        related_name='attendancerecords'

                    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ATTENDANCE_STATUS_CHOICES)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"(STUDENT: {self.student}, STATUS: {self.status})"
```

By looping over all students in the class I can create default database entries for all students and then edit afterwards